# Restful Wcf Service does not Returns objects in accurate json form

Tags: c#, android, json, rest, wcf

I developed a Restful WCF Service using framework(4.5). This service is being consumed by android client.

My Web.Config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="httpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfAndroid.Service1">
        <endpoint address=""
            behaviorConfiguration="httpBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="WcfAndroid.IService1" />

      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

My Interface IService1 :

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="/GetEmp/{empid}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function GetEmp(ByVal EmpId As String) As DataTable

<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="/GetEmpList/{empid}", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Function GetEmpList(ByVal empid As String) As Employee
```

My Service :

```
Public Function GetEmp(ByVal EmpId As String) As DataTable Implements IService1.GetEmp
    Dim table As New DataTable("mytable")
    table.Columns.Add("Result", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("acc", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("name", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("paid", GetType(Double))
    '' Using EmpId for Fetching data from Database
    table.Rows.Add("True", EmpId, "Employee1", 5000)
    table.Rows.Add("True", "2", "Employee2", 2000)
    Return table
End Function
Public Function GetEmpList(empid As String) As Employee Implements IService1.GetEmpList
    ' Using EmpId for Fetching data from Database
    ' For Testing Manual Entry is Done

    Dim EmpKey As String = """2016/Emp""/12"

    Return New Employee With {.EmpID = empid, .EmpKey = EmpKey, .EmpName = "EmployeeName", .EmpPay = "20000"}
End Function

<DataContract()>
Public Class Employee
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property EmpID As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property EmpKey As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property EmpName As String

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property EmpPay As Decimal
End Class
```

Every thing is fine while calling *GetEmpList*, except the EmpKey. It contains many special characters like slash, backSlash,DoubleQuotes. In code above i have sent manually the EmpKey which is **"2016/Emp"/12**
But it is not returning the exact key data. The returning output is

> {"EmpID":"1010","EmpKey":"\"2016/Emp\"/12","EmpName":"EmployeeName","EmpPay":20000}

where EmpKey is Incorrect.

How to sent actual data to android client? I am using HttpURLConnection in android.

Answer (score 0):

you can getValue of EmpKey from JsonObject. It can parse it as :

```
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(respons);
 String EmpKey = jobj.getString("EmpKey");
```